# Keep Bluetooth always on - xamarin mvvmcross/Android

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm developing an app for a tablet by using mvvmcross/android and I need to keep the Bluetooth always on. It's an app for employees to clock on/off in their works. I'am connecting a NFC Reader via Bluetooth when the app starts. The problem is that after some minutes the Bluetooth turns off automatically and I lose the connection with the reader. Is there some way to keep the Bluetooth always on programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some way to keep the Bluetooth always on programmatically?

There is no such API that keeps the BlueTooth always on, as it is always on, unless user turned it off or certain app turned it off. You need to find out the cause of that.

As a temp workaround for this issue, you can try to detect the bluetooth state change using a broadcast receiver. Please see [Setting up BlueTooth](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#SettingUp):

1. Define the permissions to conduct bluetooth:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   ```
2. Create a BroadCastReceiver to detect the bluetooth's state change and request to reopen the bluetooth when current state is off:

   ```
   public class BlueToothStatesChangeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
   {
       public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
       {
           //current state of bluetooth
           int current=int.Parse(intent.Extras.Get(BluetoothAdapter.ExtraState).ToString());
           //previous state of bluetooth
           int previous = int.Parse(intent.Extras.Get(BluetoothAdapter.ExtraPreviousState).ToString());

           switch (current)
           {
               case (int)Android.Bluetooth.State.Off:
                   //current state is off then we enable bluetooth here:
                   BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
                   Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ActionRequestEnable);
                   ((MainActivity)context).StartActivityForResult(enableBtIntent,1);
                   break;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Register BroadcastReceiver on your app's start and register the OnActivityResult:

   ```
   public class MainActivity : Activity
   {

       BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
       BlueToothStatesChangeReceiver btReceiver;
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

           // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
           SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
           //register broadcast receiver
           btReceiver = new BlueToothStatesChangeReceiver();
           IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ActionStateChanged);

           this.RegisterReceiver(btReceiver, filter);
       }

       protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
       {
           base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

           if (requestCode == 1)
           {
               if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
               {
                   //BlueTooth open successfully.
               }
               else if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
               {
                   //BlueTooth open failed
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Notes: This requires your current context(MainActivity) not to be destroyed.

Comment: My experience contradicts your statement "BlueTooth... is always on... unless user turned it off or certain app turned it off".  I have a tablet, provisioned to never turn off and the bluetooth connection seems to drop when the tablet screen goes darker.  Then if I touch the screen, the bluetooth connection is restored.  Are you sure there isn't some sort of power saving feature going on here?  This was on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A running Android 8.1 - QR code provisioned with a device owner that sets Settings.Global.STAY_ON_WHILE_PLUGGED_IN.